# How do you use the Cordova CLI to add a specific version of the Cordova framework

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

Cordova provides a CLI for instantiating and building a Cordova framework.

For example you can type:

```
cordova create ...
```

to create the directory structure for building a Cordova app.

You can also type:

```
cordova platform add android
cordova plugin add ...
cordova build android
```

to add the files for an android project, add plugins and build it.

These commands however seem to add the latest version of Cordova itself currently cordova3.4.0. What if you wanted to build with an earlier, post 3.0, version of Cordova like cordova3.1.0. How would you do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From node.js run this command `sudo npm uninstall cordova -g` to uninstall the current version and to install the specific version run this command `sudo npm install -g cordova@3.1.0`

Check this [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)

Comment: Very good. I didnt realize the versions of the CLI tools were tied 1-1 to the versions of the Cordova platform.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure quite what you are looking for, but here are instructions on running multiple versions of cordova on the same machine: http://www.mooreds.com/wordpress/archives/1379

Short version, use the `npm install cordova@[version]` command to install cordova in the current directory, and use the `cordova` command in `node_modules/cordova/bin` for all your project commands.

To find out the available versions of cordova, run `npm view cordova`.