# How to create a signed APK file using Cordova command line interface?

Tags: android, cordova, ant

I made a sample application named `checkStatus`. Now I want to create a signed APK file. So I can install it in different devices for my testing.

For this, I Googled and found this [documentation](http://vincentpeters.be/signing-a-cordova-android-apk-from-the-command-line/).

As per the document, I switched to my project directory and ran the following command:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore key-name.keystore -alias alias-name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

After I ran the above command, I got a file named `key-name.keystore` at `projectRoot/key-name.keystore`.

And then I copy-pasted that file into `projectRoot/platforms/android/key-name.keystore`.

After that, I created a file named `ant.properties` and saved it in `projectRoot/platforms/android`.

I wrote the following code inside the file:

```
key.store=projectRoot/key-name.keystore
key.alias=myApp
```

After that, I ran the following command to release

```
Cordova builds android --release
```

It's throwing the following error:

```
 /home/projectRoot/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: release,-f,/home/projectRoot/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen

 Error: /home/projectRoot/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
```

So this time, I modified `key.store` value in `ant.properties` file like in the following way.

```
 key.store=/home/projectRoot/platforms/android/key-name.keystore
```

Again, I ran the `cordova build android --release` command. It throws the same error.

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: starting with cordova 5, the process changes a little bit: http://ilee.co.uk/Sign-Releases-with-Cordova-Android/#comment-2054560088

Comment: both links are dead.

Answer (score 332, accepted):

## Step 1:

```
D:\projects\Phonegap\Example> cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.console --save
```

add the `--save` so that it removes the plugin from the `config.xml` file.

## Step 2:

To generate a release build for Android, we first need to make a small change to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file found in platforms/android. Edit the file and change the line:

```
<application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

and change `android:debuggable` to `false`:

```
<application android:debuggable="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

As of cordova 6.2.0 remove the android:debuggable tag completely. Here is the explanation from cordova:

> Explanation for issues of type "HardcodedDebugMode":
>      It's best to leave out the android:debuggable attribute from the manifest.
>      If you do, then the tools will automatically insert android:debuggable=true
>      when building an APK to debug on an emulator or device. And when you
>      perform a release build, such as Exporting APK, it will automatically set
>      it to false.

If on the other hand you specify a specific value in the manifest file,
   then the tools will always use it. This can lead to accidentally publishing
   your app with debug information.

## Step 3:

Now we can tell cordova to generate our release build:

```
D:\projects\Phonegap\Example> cordova build --release android
```

Then, we can find our unsigned APK file in `platforms/android/ant-build`. In our example, the file was `platforms/android/ant-build/Example-release-unsigned.apk`

## Step 4:

Note : We have our keystore `keystoreNAME-mobileapps.keystore` in this Git Repo, if you want to create another, please proceed with the following steps.

### Key Generation:

### Syntax:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore <keystoreName>.keystore -alias <Keystore AliasName> -keyalg <Key algorithm> -keysize <Key size> -validity <Key Validity in Days>
```

### Egs:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore NAME-mobileapps.keystore -alias NAMEmobileapps -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000


keystore password? : xxxxxxx
What is your first and last name? :  xxxxxx
What is the name of your organizational unit? :  xxxxxxxx
What is the name of your organization? :  xxxxxxxxx
What is the name of your City or Locality? :  xxxxxxx
What is the name of your State or Province? :  xxxxx
What is the two-letter country code for this unit? :  xxx
```

Then the Key store has been generated with name as NAME-mobileapps.keystore

## Step 5:

Place the generated keystore in

old version cordova

```
D:\projects\Phonegap\Example\platforms\android\ant-build
```

New version cordova

```
D:\projects\Phonegap\Example\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk
```

To sign the unsigned APK, run the jarsigner tool which is also included in the JDK:

### Syntax:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore <keystorename> <Unsigned APK file> <Keystore Alias name>
```

### Egs:

```
D:\projects\Phonegap\Example\platforms\android\ant-build> jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore NAME-mobileapps.keystore Example-release-unsigned.apk xxxxxmobileapps
```

OR

```
D:\projects\Phonegap\Example\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk> jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore NAME-mobileapps.keystore Example-release-unsigned.apk xxxxxmobileapps

Enter KeyPhrase as 'xxxxxxxx'
```

This signs the apk in place.

## Step 6:

Finally, we need to run the zip align tool to optimize the APK:

```
D:\projects\Phonegap\Example\platforms\android\ant-build> zipalign -v 4 Example-release-unsigned.apk Example.apk
```

OR

```
D:\projects\Phonegap\Example\platforms\android\ant-build> C:\Phonegap\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\zipalign -v 4 Example-release-unsigned.apk Example.apk
```

OR

```
D:\projects\Phonegap\Example\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk> C:\Phonegap\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\zipalign -v 4 Example-release-unsigned.apk Example.apk
```

Now we have our final release binary called example.apk and we can release this on the Google Play Store.

Comment: Okay I accept your thought. But I have private git repository and we have a team for work on mobile app. So it is comfortable for me.

Comment: Why was it important to remove org.apache.cordova.console?

Comment: Cordova.console plugin is used for debugging purpose. That why we have removed from production app. Because production app didn't need that. And if we removed that plugin it will be reduce the app size also.

Comment: Looks a bit scary, but went through the steps with ease. Nice one! Also, latest cordova has changes in the release apk directory.

Comment: @cfprabhu Step 5 is throwing a warning "No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped.". Fixed it by adding "-tsa timestamp.digicert.com" to the command. Might be useful for other users

Comment: zipalign under OSX is available at ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/zipalign

Comment: @ThomasBormans somehow `-tsa timestamp.digicert.com` threw a NullPointerException for me. `-tsa http://timestamp.digicert.com` seems to fix it

Comment: @aswzen can you give me some more details regarding your issue plz?

Comment: @cfprabhu i am commenting a comment.. by the way in windows, default android sdk if installed from latest cordova console was `C:\Users\[PC Username]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools` ..zip align tool was there

Comment: be careful with Key Generation...if you playing with google play store

Comment: Hello, I did it in the past following your steps. but in a different computer now step 4 prompts: `error de herramienta de claves: java.io.FileNotFoundException: NAME-~/.android/release.keystore (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: NAME-~/.android/release.keystore (No such file or directory)` any idea why? ( using `keytool -genkey -v -keystore NAME-~/.android/release.keystore -alias appName -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000` )

Comment: Please make sure that folder have your keystore file.

Comment: I've made all of these steps and everything works like a charm! Thank you. I'm a frontend developer not familiar with Cordova/Android/Android Studio/etc., so you saved me tons of hours.

Comment: @artuska Thank you. Happy coding. If you need any help on cordova contact me cfprabhu@yahoo.com

Comment: if you are running with the problem of "c:\program is not recognized" then pls use ""[double quote] from start to end eg D:\projects\Phonegap\Example\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk> "C:\Phonegap\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\zipalign" -v 4 Example-release-unsigned.apk Example.apk ]

Comment: The only guide that helped me, THANK YOU MAN!

Answer (score 134):

An update to @malcubierre for Cordova 4 (and later)-

Create a file called `release-signing.properties` and put in  `APPFOLDER\platforms\android` folder

Contents of the file: edit after = for all except 2nd line

```
storeFile=C:/yourlocation/app.keystore
storeType=jks
keyAlias=aliasname
keyPassword=aliaspass
storePassword=password
```

Then this command should build a release version:

```
cordova build android --release
```

UPDATE - This was not working for me `Cordova 10 with android 9` - The build was replacing the release-signing.properties file.  I had to make a `build.json` file and drop it in the appfolder, same as root.  And this is the contents - replace as above:

```
{
"android": {
    "release": {
       "keystore": "C:/yourlocation/app.keystore",
        "storePassword": "password",
        "alias": "aliasname",
        "password" : "aliaspass",
        "keystoreType": ""
    }
}
}
```

Run it and it will generate one of those `release-signing.properties` in the android folder

Comment: Thanks! You can also change the name/location of your properties file, but you have to specify in a `build-extras.gradle` file. Relevant cordova doc [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#extending-buildgradle).

Comment: My app is not getting update to next version, first version created in ant build(cordova 3). I upgraded my cordova to 6.0.0 now second version is created in gradle build, I followed the latest cordova doc to create signed apk but still my app not getting updated. I gone through the all the info of the web but still somewhere am going wrong. Please help me @Dunc

Comment: @Naveen I'm using Cordova 5.2.0, had various problems with other versions > 5.  Suggest you [try that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22166056/188926) if you can.  Then, if still having problems, I recommend asking a new question.

Comment: Still having problem, new version of apk is not getting downloaded from existing app. @Dunc

Comment: @Dunc any solution

Comment: @Naveen Not sure I can help, it's probably best if you start a new SO question detailing your specific issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: I asked this question so many times and ended up in blocking  stackoverflow, I can only comment here that's why asking like this. If you know something please help me@Dunc

Comment: @Jon. Thanks for the solution. But i am getting the apk with name android-release. Is there a way to name my apk? please help

Comment: you can rename the apk like any file in windows (etc).  I just upload the xxx-relese.apk to google play, and all the encoded app name etc from manifest /config etc shows up on the play store.  I am not sure if there is any difference  as to the name of the actual apk.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663991/keystore-and-key-alias & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034899/how-to-retrieve-key-alias-and-key-password-for-signed-apk-in-android-studiomigr

Comment: Would again like to point out the docs.  They outline a few different ways to sign, including gradle.  https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#using-buildjson

Comment: this answer does not works, I dont know why it has so many upvotes

Comment: You still need to run zipalign on the signed apk like in cfprabhu 's answer

Comment: Note that if you do not want to store the passwords in the file, just remove the password lines.  When building, cordova will prompt for the passwords.

Comment: Works with cordova 8.0.0

Comment: the dot after aliaspass is confusing. Reproduce the same password with "password" : "aliaspass",

Answer (score 60):

In the current [documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html#signing-an-app) we can specify a build.json with the keystore:

```
{
     "android": {
         "debug": {
             "keystore": "..\android.keystore",
             "storePassword": "android",
             "alias": "mykey1",
             "password" : "password",
             "keystoreType": ""
         },
         "release": {
             "keystore": "..\android.keystore",
             "storePassword": "",
             "alias": "mykey2",
             "password" : "password",
             "keystoreType": ""
         }
     }
 }
```

And then, execute the commando with --buildConfig argumente, this way:

```
cordova run android --buildConfig
```

Comment: Awesome <3 your answer is about files that I can version control!

Comment: in which directory should this json exist?

Comment: cordova build android --release

Comment: Place the build.json in the root project folder along with the keystore file.  This is the most effective hassle free method for signing I've found.

Comment: For some reason the file path I had to changed to "../android.keystore". (forward slash)

Comment: Best answer! Thanks. :)

Comment: This one I like :)

Comment: Do we still need to run `zipalign` after this?

Comment: From cordova 5.0, I don't need to use --buildConfig, just with having the build.json at the top of the folder (the main folder) works, and when I need to publish on Google Play, I just use cordova build android --release.

Comment: Note that if you do not want to store the passwords in the file, just remove the password lines.  When building, cordova will prompt for the passwords.

Comment: good solution, simple. I just run cordova build android --release

Comment: It appears I had to use `"keystoreType": "jks"` here.

Comment: So `cordova run android --buildConfig` and then `zipalign` the output? There is no way to teach cordova do it for us?

Answer (score 20):

**Step1:**

Go to `cordova\platforms\android` ant create a fille called `ant.properties` file with the keystore file info (this keystore can be generated from your favorite Android SDK, studio...):

```
key.store=C:\\yourpath\\Yourkeystore.keystore
key.alias=youralias
```

**Step2:**

Go to cordova path and execute:

```
cordova build android --release
```

Note: You will be prompted asking your keystore and key password

An YourApp-release.apk will appear in `\cordova\platforms\android\ant-build`

Comment: starting with cordova 5, the process changes a little bit: http://ilee.co.uk/Sign-Releases-with-Cordova-Android/#comment-2054560088

Comment: With Cordova 5 name file "release-signing.properties" instead of "ant.properties"; all other steps are exactly as described by @malcubierre

Comment: new version of apk is not getting downloaded from existing app in cordova 6.0.0. I followed all the docs still not solved my issue can you help me @MarioOrlandi

Answer (score 11):

**In cordova 6.2.0**, it has an easy way to create release build. refer to other steps here [Steps 1, 2 and 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26450074/1923045)

```
cd cordova/ #change to root cordova folder
platforms/android/cordova/clean #clean if you want
cordova build android --release -- --keystore="/path/to/keystore" --storePassword=password --alias=alias_name #password will be prompted if you have any
```

Comment: I am getting an error of `The system cannot find the file specified` using Cordova 6.2.0

Comment: have you replaced the keystore path? If so please post the command here.

Comment: Yep. It's `cordova build android --release -- --keystore="C:\release.keystore" --storePassword=****** --alias=mr5`

Comment: After enclosing my password with `"`(double quote), it started to run. I think Cordova has an issue about parsing special characters.

Comment: If anyone use Ionic, you can checkout this document http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/build/

Answer (score 7):

On Mac (osx), I generated two .sh files, one for the first publication and another one for updating :

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Ionic to Signed APK ---- b@agencys.eu // Benjamin Rathelot\n"
printf "Project dir : "
read DIR
printf "Project key alias : "
read ALIAS
cd $DIR/
cordova build --release android
cd platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias $ALIAS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore android-release-unsigned.apk $ALIAS
zipalign -v 4 android-release-unsigned.apk signedApk.apk
```

And to update your app:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Ionic to Signed APK ---- b@agencys.eu // Benjamin Rathelot\n"
printf "Project dir : "
read DIR
printf "Project key alias : "
read ALIAS
cd $DIR/
cordova build --release android
cd platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/
rm signedApk.apk
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore android-release-unsigned.apk $ALIAS
zipalign -v 4 android-release-unsigned.apk signedApk.apk
```

Assuming you're in your home folder or a folder topping your apps folders. Make sure to set correctly chmod to use this script. Then :

```
./ionicToApk.sh # or whatever depending of the name of your file, in CLI
```

Your signed apk will be in Your App folder/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/ as SignedApk.apk
Make sure to use the correct key alias and password defined with the first script

Answer (score 3):

```
##Generated signed apk from commandline
#variables
APP_NAME=THE_APP_NAME
APK_LOCATION=./
APP_HOME=/path/to/THE_APP
APP_KEY=/path/to/Android_key
APP_KEY_ALIAS=the_alias
APP_KEY_PASSWORD=123456789
zipalign=$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/28.0.3/zipalign

#the logic
cd $APP_HOME
cordova build --release android
cd platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore $APP_KEY ./app-release-unsigned.apk $APP_KEY_ALIAS <<< $APP_KEY_PASSWORD
rm -rf "$APK_LOCATION/$APP_NAME.apk"
$zipalign -v 4 ./app-release-unsigned.apk "$APK_LOCATION/$APP_NAME.apk"
open $APK_LOCATION
#the end
```

Answer (score 2):

Build cordova release APK file in cmd.

**KEY STORE FILE PATH**: keystore file path (F:/cordova/myApp/xxxxx.jks)

**KEY STORE PASSWORD**: xxxxx

**KEY STORE ALIAS**: xxxxx

**KEY STORE ALIAS PASSWORD**: xxxxx

**PATH OF zipalign.exe**: zipalign.exe file path (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\zipalign)

**ANDROID UNSIGNED APK NAME**: android-release-unsigned.apk

**ANDROID RELEASE APK NAME**: android-release.apk

**Run below steps in cmd (run as administrator)**

1. cordova build --release android
2. go to android-release-unsigned.apk file location (PROJECT\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk)
3. jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore <**KEY STORE FILE PATH**> <**ANDROID UNSIGNED APK NAME**> <**KEY STORE ALIAS**>
4. <**PATH OF zipalign.exe**> -v 4 <**ANDROID UNSIGNED APK NAME**> <**ANDROID RELEASE APK NAME**>

Answer (score 1):

First Check your version code and version name if you are updating your app. And make sure you have a previous keystore.

If you are updating app then follow step 1,3,4.

## Step 1:

Goto your cordova project for generate our release build:

```
D:\projects\Phonegap\Example> cordova build --release android
```

Then, we can find our unsigned APK file in platforms/android/ant-build. In our example, the file was

if u used ant-build

```
yourproject/platforms/android/ant-build/Example-release-unsigned.apk
```

**OR**

if u used gradle-build

```
yourProject/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/Example-release-unsigned.apk
```

## Step 2:

### Key Generation:

### Syntax:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore <keystoreName>.keystore -alias <Keystore AliasName> -keyalg <Key algorithm> -keysize <Key size> -validity <Key Validity in Days>
```

if keytool command not recognize do this step

Check that the directory the keytool executable is in is on your path. (For example, on my Windows 7 machine, it's in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin.)

### Example:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore NAME-mobileapps.keystore -alias NAMEmobileapps -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000


keystore password? : xxxxxxx
What is your first and last name? :  xxxxxx
What is the name of your organizational unit? :  xxxxxxxx
What is the name of your organization? :  xxxxxxxxx
What is the name of your City or Locality? :  xxxxxxx
What is the name of your State or Province? :  xxxxx
What is the two-letter country code for this unit? :  xxx
```

Then the Key store has been generated with name as NAME-mobileapps.keystore

## Step 3:

Place the generated keystore in
    D:\projects\Phonegap\Example\platforms\android\ant-build

To sign the unsigned APK, run the jarsigner tool which is also included in the JDK:

### Syntax:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore <keystorename <Unsigned APK file> <Keystore Alias name>
```

If it doesn't reconize do these steps

**(1)**   Right click on "This PC" > right-click Properties > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables > select PATH then EDIT.

**(2)**    Add your jdk bin folder path to environment variables, it should look like this:

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin".

### Example:

```
D:\projects\Phonegap\Example\platforms\android\ant-build> jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore NAME-mobileapps.keystore Example-release-unsigned.apk xxxxxmobileapps

Enter KeyPhrase as 'xxxxxxxx'
```

This signs the apk in place.

## Step 4:

Finally, we need to run the zip align tool to optimize the APK:

if zipalign not recognize then

**(1)**   goto your android sdk path and find zipalign it is usually in android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.3

**(2)**  Copy zipalign file paste into your  generate release apk folder usually in below path

yourproject/platforms/android/ant-build/Example-release-unsigned.apk

```
D:\projects\Phonegap\Example\platforms\android\ant-build> zipalign -v 4 Example-release-unsigned.apk Example.apk
```

OR

```
D:\projects\Phonegap\Example\platforms\android\ant-build> C:\Phonegap\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\zipalign -v 4 Example-release-unsigned.apk Example.apk
```

Now we have our final release binary called example.apk and we can release this on the Google Play Store.

Answer (score 1):

**Great news!**
cordova 10 include the new android version with `app-release.aab`.

Answer (score 1):

At first, create a keystore:
keytool -genkeypair -keystore my.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 3072 -validity 10000 -v

According to the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/platforms/android/) `--packageType` define the file extension apk/bundle. `--` to indicate that these are platform-specific arguments
Inside the project folder run:

```
cordova build android --release -- --keystore=../../../key.keystore --storePassword="1234567890" --alias=alias_name --packageType=apk  --password="1234567890"
```

A log will appear with the apsolute file's path.
example: `/path/project/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk`

Sign the APK:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256 -keystore key.keystore project.apk alias_name
```

Verify signature:
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs project.apk

Use zipalign

```
zipalign -v 4 project.apk project.sign.apk
```

In case the error "[Failed to extract native libraries, res=-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55173004/targeting-sdk-android-q-results-in-failed-to-finalize-session-install-failed-i)" when installing:

```
zipalign -p 4 project.apk project.sign.apk
```

Final step is to delete the history because leaving clear text passwords in your history is a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, I've created a `build.cmd` file:

(replace the keystore path and alias)

For Cordova:

```
@echo off 
set /P spassw="Store Password: " && set /P kpassw="Key Password: " && cordova build android --release -- --keystore=../../local/my.keystore --storePassword=%spassw% --alias=tmpalias --password=%kpassw%
```

And for Ionic:

```
@echo off 
set /P spassw="Store Password: " && set /P kpassw="Key Password: " && ionic build --prod && cordova build android --release -- --keystore=../../local/my.keystore --storePassword=%spassw% --alias=tmpalias --password=%kpassw%
```

Save it in the ptoject's directory, you can double click or open it with cmd.