# Cordova build -release Android Unsigned apk

Tags: android, cordova, ant, gradle, keystore

I'm trying to generate my release apk to deploy it on Play Store.
I'm running this command

```
Sudo cordova build android --release
```

Which is generating me a file named Android-Release-Unsigned.apk

I tried many solutions, like creating keystore

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore key-name.keystore -alias alias-name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

or the trick of creating a Ant.properties file like [here](http://vincentpeters.be/signing-a-cordova-android-apk-from-the-command-line/) and none of them worked at all.

Any other possible solution for this ? Cordova version is 5.1.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create signed APK file using cordova command line interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449512/how-to-create-signed-apk-file-using-cordova-command-line-interface)

Answer (score 4):

Create a file called `release-signing.properties` and put in  APPFOLDER\platforms\android folder  Cordova used to use `ant.properties` but now ignores that file.

Contents of the file: edit after = for all except 2nd line

```
storeFile=C:/yourlocation/app.keystore
storeType=jks
keyAlias=aliasname
keyPassword=aliaspass
storePassword=password
```

Now running `cordova build android --release` should produce a signed version.

Answer (score 3):

If you have keystore file generated, this should work.

You may also need to remove **console plugin** if the same apk directly goes to production.

**In cordova 6.2.0**

```
cd cordova/ #change to root cordova folder
platforms/android/cordova/clean #clean if you want
cordova build android --release -- --keystore="/path/to/keystore" --storePassword=password --alias=alias_name #password will be prompted if you have any
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I couldn't comment. Possible duplicate?

[How to create a signed APK file using Cordova command line interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449512/how-to-create-singed-apk-file-using-cordova-command-line-interface)

This worked perfect for me.

Comment: I already tried this solution but it still generating "android-release-unsigned.apk"