# example-release-unsigned.apk not changing after "cordova build --release android"

Tags: cordova, versioning

Creating signed apk, First version already there but second version is not creating, when I run this `cordova build --release android` command `example-release-unsigned.apk` is still in first version only. Working on cordova 6.0.0 please help

Comment: Are you not using keytool to sign the app?

Comment: Then you should get example-release-signed.apk, not unsigned version.

Comment: @Avijit Thats old version of apk noy new one

Comment: I added a release-signing.properties as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449512/how-to-create-signed-apk-file-using-cordova-command-line-interface