# Generated signed Android APK (Cordova)

Tags: android, cordova, jar, zipalign, signed-apk

I am trying to build a signed apk for Android platform using cordova.
I have already created unsigned apk using cordova --release android.
But i am unable to sign usejarsigner and zipalign.
kindly help.

Comment: Why are you unable to use them? Do you get some errors?

Comment: See this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449512/how-to-create-signed-apk-file-using-cordova-command-line-interface

Comment: I was not giving apk path in zipalign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solved my problem.
I am explaining its steps for the people who are still stuck in it:

1. Create a unsigned apk.
   Run this command `cordova --release android` after getting to the location of the project.
2. You can find the unsigned apk in 
   project_name\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk
3. Copy this apk and keystore tool in one folder.
   Navigate to the folder and sign it using jarsigner present in java.
   Run this command,
   `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore <keystorename <Unsigned APK file> <Keystore Alias name>`
4. After this you will be prompt to enter password of keystore.
5. Go to location of zipalign.
   (it is present in Android\SDK\build-tools\version)
6. Run this command
   `zipalign -v 4 "location of signed apk" "location of aligned apk"`