# Debbugable Android App

Tags: android, google-play, apk, debug-build

I have the following error when I try to publish on google play.

> You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to
>   disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play

I ve set the Manifest.xml to `debbugable=false` but it won't work.

Comment: Have you signed your release build?

Answer (score 0):

You must change your Build variants to Release, before publishing to Play Store,
You will also require to provide KeyStore credentials

[Refer this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)

Answer (score 0):

As the Google says! Follow these steps

**Step 1** Go to Build>Generate Signed APK>Next (module selected would be your module , most often called "app")

**Step 2** Click on create new

**Step 3** Basically, fill in the form with the required details. The confusing bit it is where it asks for a Key Store Path. Click on the icon on the right with the 3 dots ("..."), which will open up a navigator window asking you to navigate and select a .jks file.Navigate to a folder where you want your keystore file saved and then at the File Name box at the bottom of that window, simply enter a name of your liking and the OK button will be clickable now. What is happening is that the window isnt really asking you chose a .jks file but rather it wants you to give it the location and name that you want it to have.

**Step 4** Click on Next and then select Release and Voila ! you are done.

Comment: my project is a cordova build project and I've done all the settingin CMD

Comment: Then you can follow the steps as described in following link; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449512/how-to-create-signed-apk-file-using-cordova-command-line-interface