# Can't install unsigned Cordova apk

Tags: android, cordova

I just built a basic Cordova image, but I can't install it on my Android phone.

It says the package is corrupted.

I have enabled "Trust unknown sources" and copied the file onto my Nexus 6P.

The build process doesn't throw any errors, it creates a `android-release-unsigned.apk` file as expected.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: I have the same problem, although the guide I followed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449512/how-to-create-a-signed-apk-file-using-cordova-command-line-interface was updated this past February.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem as you because I followed the guide I linked in the comments above; that guide is for building a *release* build, not a *test* build.

In order to build a test build, do:

```
cordova build android
```

Which should create a file called **debug-build.apk**

In addition, if you have an android device [set up for development](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html), you can run:

```
cordova run android --device
```