# Targeting SDK Android Q results in Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-2

Tags: android, android-10.0

Once I switch my target api to 'Q' I cannot install the APK on Android Q Emulator.  I get error:

> Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Failed to
>   extract native libraries, res=-2

Android Studio (v3.3.2) recommends I uninstall apk first.  I tried uninstalling apk and I still get the same error.  App work if I downgrade target api to 28.

Comment: same issue on real device (running Q)

Comment: same error on my pixel 2

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This happens because of an issue with zipalign, see - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37045367. You need to set `extractNativeLibs` in your Application Tag on AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:extractNativeLibs="true"
...
>
```

If you are using `adb` to install the apk try adding `-t` flag

```
adb install -t <path-to-apk>
```

Comment: Tried it, does not help

Comment: adb install -t apk-free.apk 
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install apk-free.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-2]

Comment: Try adding the following to defaultConfig in app/build.gradle file  `   packagingOptions{
        doNotStrip "*/armeabi/*.so"
        doNotStrip "*/armeabi-v7a/*.so"
        doNotStrip "*/x86/*.so"
    } `

Comment: Also make sure any old version of the apk is uninstalled

Comment: Can you share relevant extracts from your app/build.gradle and Manifest?

Comment: Looks like this might be a zipalign issue, can you try setting `extractNativeLibs` to true instead? - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37045367

Comment: If my answer helped, I'd appreciate if you can accept it as a solution!

Comment: With latest gradle version 3.6.0 or greater, android sdk tools 28.0.3 or higher, gradle automatically replacing extractNativeLibs false. So better to use -p option to zipalign commend as like below
zipalign -v -p 4 app.apk app-aligned.apk

Comment: It did help on my side using Xamarin.Android. The issue appeared after manually adding AndroidX components.

Comment: you deserve a crown! great catch, indeed i am using zipalign and that was the  issue.

Answer (score 12):

If you want `android:extractNativeLibs="false"`, use zipalign with `-p` key in order to page align ELFs within ZIP:

```
zipalign -p 4 app.apk app-aligned.apk
```

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error in AWS Device Farm. Turns out they have sdk version 21 installed and my `minSdkVersion` was set to 24. Lowering my `minSdkVersion` to 21 resolved this. This error was getting returned on trying to install apk on the test device. Hope this helps for anyone else setting up device farm on android.