# How to pull, decompress, sign, build and install APK file with native libraries?

Tags: android, apk, apktool

I'm trying to pull an APK file, modify it, then re-install to phone. I'm using adb, apktool and jarsigner. I'll call the APK file, 1.arm64_v8a.apk.

1. `adb pull /data/ .. /1.arm64_v8a.apk` to pull the file from android to my computer.
2. `apktool decode 1.arm64_v8a.apk -o 1.arm64_v8a` to decompress the APK
3. `apktool build --use-aapt 1.arm64_v8a -o 1.arm64_v8a.apk` to build a new APK.
4. sign apk `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore keystore 1.arm64_v8a.apk mykey`
5. Install APK to phone `adb install 1.arm64_v8a.apk` which produces: `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-2]`

Comment: Did you tried adding "--use-aapt2" instead of "--use-aapt"?

Comment: @emandt Tried aapt and aapt2 - no luck.

Comment: Did you tried to open resigned APK using a decompressing software (i.e: 7zip) from your PC? Is it still working? Try also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55173004/targeting-sdk-android-q-results-in-failed-to-finalize-session-install-failed-i

Comment: @emandt - yup. Extracted the new apk using Linux unzip. Everything seem correct.