# How to sign apk with own keystore file in debug mode?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, android-app-signing

I want to sign my apk with my keystore file in debug build also ,i have created a build.json file with following info

```
{
"android": {
    "debug": {
        "keystore": "..//my.keystore",
        "alias": "alias",
        "password": "password",
        "storePassword": "password"
    },
    "release": {
        "keystore": "..//my.keystore",
        "alias": "alias",
        "password": "password",
        "storePassword": "password"
    }
}
}
```

when i build the apk with command ionic cordova build android --debug --buildconfig
it still sign the apk with default key not mine
for ionic cordova build android --release --buildconfig
it is fine it is signing with my key 
i have verified in signing-config.json
i am following this documentation
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/#signing-an-app
Please help
[image]

Comment: i think what you're asking is related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449512/how-to-create-a-signed-apk-file-using-cordova-command-line-interface)

Answer (score 0):

I usually do that using Android Studio instead of using the Cordova tools. Maybe that's a valid way to do it for you.

Comment: can you explain how to do with android studio?

Comment: Open with Android Studio the platforms/android directory.  
Open the Project Structure (Strg + Alt + Shift + S). Navigate to Module and choose app. Click on the tab Signing Configs, add a new config and fill the input fields. Then you navigate to Build Variants and choose there app, too. Under Build Types -> debug fill your new created signing config into the the field Signing Config.

Comment: Still android studio signed the apk with default debug key

Comment: Problem Solved i just need to move the newly  
buildTypes {
    debug {
      signingConfig signingConfigs.Zand
    } add code after cordova setting its signing config to overrirde
Thanks durzan